# bbc micro bit radio string broadcast

Tags: python, embedded, bbc-microbit

I have some really simple code, which I want to build up to detect button presses and then send out the button status using the radio function. But I cannot get the code to work, I thought setting the string with a fix text and then broadcast using the radio function would just work, but seem to be getting an error. I don't want to do via if states, as I will add more into the string with different sensor values and button presses etc.

```
from microbit import *
import radio

radio.config(group=0)
radio.on()

while True:

     button_status_a = "Button A pressed"

     radio.send(button_status_a)
     sleep(1000)
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say how you are detecting the transmission. There is a working example of sending and receiving simple messages using button presses at this question:

[BBC Bit Micro - Radio string transfer random carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205403/bbc-bit-micro-radio-string-transfer-random-carriage-returns/44220479#44220479)

The example uses if statements which you say you want to avoid. These are used to detect the button press.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as written will work, transmitting that fixed text message every second, on group 0, with no error.  Make sure that you write a receiving program that is also on radio group 0.  Here's an example of a program that receives and shows messages:

```
from microbit import *
import radio

radio.config(group=0)
radio.on()

while True:

    incoming = radio.receive()
    if incoming:
        display.show(incoming, delay=200)
```